# function delaying on node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Im on a big problem, I need to do an application that gets trello content as soon as i can but i dont know why my for isnt working as it should do. when i the output of this should be the card id and when the function is called it should show the member. I dont know why, but when the 'miembro' function is called, it delays and it is shown after the second id, so its delayed a lot and i need them to show one under the other. I appreciate a quick answer, thank you!

```
const trelloKB = require("trello-kb");

const fetch = require('node-fetch');
 
// Replace this by the application key of your Trello account
var appKey = '51501902fff527d305686a29d6d61cfa';
 
// Replace this by a valid authorization token
var authToken = '9828f5f03073ae52ffdae77bdf49c939df8a315b169cb81aeb42a3d43d0f9e21';

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}   

function miembros (id){
     fetch('https://api.trello.com/1/cards/'+id+'/members?key=51501902fff527d305686a29d6d61cfa&token=9828f5f03073ae52ffdae77bdf49c939df8a315b169cb81aeb42a3d43d0f9e21&fields=fullName', {
  method: 'GET'
})
  .then(response => {
      
    setTimeout(function() {
        return(response.text());
}, 3000);
  })
  .then(text => console.log(text))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
  
    
}

 
trelloKB.get(appKey, authToken, '33CP31Sf').then(

    
  function (cards) {
    // Print the title of each card
    var ms = 3000;
    for(i=0; i<2; i++){
        
     var card = cards[0];
      var id = card.id;
      var titleCard = card.title;
    console.log(id);
    miembros(id);
    
    }  
      
    
    
    
  },

);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should learn about [synchronous and asynchronous concept](https://rowanmanning.com/posts/javascript-for-beginners-async/)

You need to use async-await and return a promise in your function `miembros()`
read this [async await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

this is my example

```
    const cards =[{id:1,title:'kimiwo'},{id:2,title:'namae wa'},{id:3,title:'udiiiin'}];
    
    yourname(cards);
    
    async function yourname (cards) {
      for(let card of cards){
        console.log(`id :${card.id},text:${card.title}`);
        let result = await(await miembros(card.id)).text();
        console.log(result);
      }
    }
    function miembros(id){
       return fetch('https://api.trello.com/1/cards/'+id+'/members?key=51501902fff527d305686a29d6d61cfa&token=9828f5f03073ae52ffdae77bdf49c939df8a315b169cb81aeb42a3d43d0f9e21&fields=fullName')
}
```

you can see the result [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0v8yom9c/)

*Edit
fetch returns promise, so you can just return `fetch` and wrap your function with async-await

Comment: Thank you so much! That link is what i needed, I dont use to develop without knowing the language but I need to finish this app asap so i need to try and fail to learn quickly, thank you again.

Comment: Hi! I would like to put this fetch function     fetch('https://api.trello.com/1/cards/'+id+'/members?key=51501902fff527d305686a29d6d61cfa&token=9828f5f03073ae52ffdae77bdf49c939df8a315b169cb81aeb42a3d43d0f9e21&fields=fullName', {
  method: 'GET'
})
  .then(response => {
      
    setTimeout(function() {
        return(response.text());
}, 3000);
  })
  .then(text => console.log(text))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

instead of showing the id in the miembros function, but when i do it it delays again, why does it happens?

Comment: I just update my answer, actually `fetch` return `Promise`. so, you can just return it

Comment: You are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

It’s delayed because you need to use a sync await or .then

You need to get the first Id first, then do a .then to get the second ID through the function call.

Also, you shouldn’t show you API keys, they’re supposed to be private lol

Comment: Thank you! I know i shouldnt do it but that board belongs to a board that i made for testing, so dont worry, thanks.